# How to display an array in a textview in Java

Tags: java, arrays, swing

I want to display an array in a text view, but it is not working. Please help me. Thanks.

I want to be the output looks this way...

example i will input 1,2,3,4,5 then..

output:
1
2
3
4
5

Here's my code:

```
String []values = ( input.getText().toString().split(","));
int[] convertedValues = new int[values.length];

for(int x=0;x<convertedValues.length;x++){
    convertedValues[x] = Integer.parseInt(values[x]);
    jLabel7.setText(Integer.toString(convertedValues[x]));
}
```

Comment: What's the point of creating `int[] convertedValues`? And also share the error message you get.

Comment: It seems you are using the same jLabel to display the values of the array.  It doesn't make sense.

Comment: it only displays my last input

Comment: @Dio Baccay because you are using in an for loop, thats why its displaying the last value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*After i see your update*: You need to pass HTML tags format string inside the JLabel component to make new line:

```
String[] values = ( input.getText().toString().split(","));
String inLineValues = "";
for (String value : values) {
    inLineValues += value + "<br/>";
}
jLabel1.setText("<html>" + inLineValues + "</html>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String []values = ( input.getText().toString().split(","));
int[] convertedValues = new int[values.length];
List<String> numbers = new ArrayList<String>();
for(int x=0;x<convertedValues.length;x++){
    convertedValues[x] = Integer.parseInt(values[x]);
    numbers.add(Integer.toString(convertedValues[x]));
}
jLabel7.setText(numbers.toString());
```

General idea is that you need to collect allvalues for output in one string, and than print it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `int[] convertedValues` variable, Try This:

```
    String[] values = (input.getText().toString().split(","));
    for (String value : values) {
        jLabel7.setText(jLabel7.getText() + " " + value );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] values = input.getText().toString().split(",");
StringBuilder allValues = new StringBuilder();
for(String value: values)
    allValues.append(value);

jLabel7.setText(allValues);
```

All you're doing is removing "," from `input.getText()`, for that you can do

```
String text = input.getText.replace(",","");
jLabel7.setText(text);
```

Comment: You create as much Objects as elements in the String array. That's not very effective.

Comment: @SteveBenett I was just providing solution. Thanks for pointing out, Now It's using `StringBuilder`. Any more improvements?